# Images in blockquotes in lists are protruding

Tags: bug, design, images

The two red lines at either side of the below image delineate the boundary of the area containing the contents of the post. Observe that the right side of the nested image extends beyond the red line.

([link to the post used for these screenshots](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-watch-questions-for-new-comments-and-answers))

> [image]
>
> Here's a high-contrast version, in case your eyes aren't sharp enough to spot that (mine nearly aren't):
>
> [image]
>
> That optical difficulty would not be replicated with an image that was not substantially white (as no doubt many images used on SE are).

Note that the offending images are within a blockquote in a list item - excessive nesting could be the cause.

Comment: Wow, all the screenshots in screenshot, and irrelevant non-freehand red squares did not make that one easy to follow. But I get the point now. For those who don't, visit the post.

Comment: @Bart - Yes, the non hand drawn red box threw me off at first too

Comment: @Bart Yeah, sorry about that; I just used the first example at hand.

Comment: @ColeJohnson [I tried.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/213144/1)

Comment: If every bug will be eeekified, it will remove the whole point of the "eeeek".